# TypeScript: tsc.exe --execute: Error cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following directory setup:

```
/app/ioc.ts
/tests/test.ts
```

I'm in the tests directory. The contents of `app/ioc.ts` are unimportant, but the contents of `tests/test.ts` are:

```
import IOC = module('../app/ioc');
var container = new IOC.Container();
```

If I compile this like so:

```
tsc test.ts
```

Then run it like so:

```
node test
```

All's good! The file runs without errors. However! If I run it like this:

```
tsc -e test.ts
```

I get the following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '../app/ioc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/dropbox/work/sandbox/Prototyping/TypeScript/tests/test.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:56041:30)
    at BatchCompiler.run (C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:56563:29)
    at BatchCompiler.batchCompile (C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:56795:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nathan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:56908:7)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The `-e` flag is being removed from tsc, partly because it doesn't play nicely with this sort of scenario. Executing arbitrary JS in the context of the compiler process turns out to not be a good idea.